# Cannot pick further dates in datepicker using jquery

Tags: jquery, datepicker, jquery-ui-datepicker

I am a newbie here , I've set the Starting Date +60 D , and I am confused on why I cannot pick further dates , my plan is that to is set a default date range +60D and I'd be able to pick further dates .here is the example link http://jsfiddle.net/jquerybyexample/LGw6F/

```
From: <input type="text" id="txtFromDate" />
To: <input type="text" id="txtToDate" />


$(document).ready(function(){
    $("#txtFromDate").datepicker({
        minDate: 0,
        maxDate: "+60D",
        numberOfMonths: 2,
        onSelect: function(selected) {
          $("#txtToDate").datepicker("option","minDate", selected)
        }
    });
    $("#txtToDate").datepicker({ 
        minDate: 0,
        maxDate:"+60D",
        numberOfMonths: 2,
        onSelect: function(selected) {
           $("#txtFromDate").datepicker("option","maxDate", selected)
        }
    });  
});
```

Comment: What I understood: You want to pick the first date between today and 60days in the future AND THEN pick a second date between it and another 60days in the future from the first selected date?

Comment: @Daidon, no sir , what I mean is that , I was able to set the default date +60D, but the problem is I cannot pick further dates , like is there any way to set the default date range and I can still pick further dates ?

Comment: Based on your code, maxDate is only set for +60 days (after the current date) thus you cannot choose further dates. What do you really want to happen? If you want to start picking dates after 60 days of the current date then you should sen the minDate instead of the maxDate.

Comment: what i want to happen is that their will be a default date that is the current date plus 60 days and I can still pick further dates ,or I can pick my own date.

Comment: Default date is the starting date right? We're kinda confused on what you what to happen really.

Comment: maxDate limits your MAXIMUM DATE pick.

Comment: @Ronald Yes , the default date will be the current date plus 60 days and my problem is that , I can no longer pick further dates. Yes I understand that the maximum date is 60 days , is there any other way on how to set the datepicker to have a default date which will be the current date plus 60 days and still I will be able to pick any dates , because as what you can see on my example I can only pick the current date between 60 days.

Comment: set the minDate to +60 instead of maxDate.

Comment: @Teapetetose Did Ronald's answer solve your problem?

Comment: @Daidon No, Any thoughts ?

Comment: @Teapetetose, huh? what do you really want to happen? you said that default date should be +60 days and you should be able to pick further. Kindly give an example and clarify your question.

Comment: @Teapetetose, at least you should have up-voted my answer for the effort. Hihihi ;)

Comment: @Ronald oops , done mate, thanks for helping me out . I'm sorry if my questions are not clear.

Comment: @Teapetetose, no problem. Hope to get you the correct answer next time. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To pre-populate your input-field ("put a default date"), do this:

```js
$(function(){
    $("#txtFromDate").datepicker({
        minDate:0,
        maxDate: "+60D",
        numberOfMonths: 2,
    });
    $("#txtToDate").datepicker({ 
        minDate:0,
        maxDate:"+60D",
        numberOfMonths: 2,
    });
    var default_date = new Date();
    default_date.setDate(default_date.getDate()+60);
    $('#txtFromDate').datepicker('setDate', new Date());
    $('#txtToDate').datepicker('setDate', default_date);
});
$("#txtFromDate").datepicker({
        onSelect: function(dateText) {
            $("#txtToDate").datepicker("option", "minDate", $('#txtFromDate').datepicker("getDate") );
            var date2 = $("#txtFromDate").datepicker("getDate");
            date2.setDate(date2.getDate()+60);
            $("#txtToDate").datepicker("option", "maxDate", date2);
        }
    });
```

```css
body
{
    font-size:8pt;
    font-family:Verdana;
    padding: 5px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
<br/>
From: <input type="text" id="txtFromDate" />
To: <input type="text" id="txtToDate" />

<!-- begin snippet: js hide: false console: true babel: false -->
```

Full HTML-example:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Test</title>
<style>
body
{
    font-size:8pt;
    font-family:Verdana;
    padding: 5px;
}
</style>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/themes/base/jquery-ui.css">
</head>
<body>
    
<br/>
From: <input type="text" id="txtFromDate" />
To: <input type="text" id="txtToDate" />

<script type="text/javascript">
$(function(){
 $("#txtFromDate").datepicker({
  minDate:0,
  maxDate: "+60D",
  numberOfMonths: 2,
 });
 $("#txtToDate").datepicker({ 
  minDate:0,
  maxDate:"+60D",
  numberOfMonths: 2,
 }); 
 var default_date = new Date();
 default_date.setDate(default_date.getDate()+60);
 $('#txtFromDate').datepicker('setDate', new Date());
 $('#txtToDate').datepicker('setDate', default_date);
});
$("#txtFromDate").datepicker({
    onSelect: function(dateText) {
        $("#txtToDate").datepicker("option", "minDate", $('#txtFromDate').datepicker("getDate") );
        var date2 = $("#txtFromDate").datepicker("getDate");
        date2.setDate(date2.getDate()+60);
        $("#txtToDate").datepicker("option", "maxDate", date2);
    }
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

I hope this is what you want.
Regards

Answer (score 2):

Updated again based on the latest comment.

Updated the jFiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/LGw6F/2230/)

```
$(document).ready(function(){
   $("#txtFromDate").datepicker({ 
    dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
    changeMonth: true,
    minDate: new Date(),
    numberOfMonths: 2,
    onSelect: function(selected) {
          $("#txtToDate").datepicker("option","minDate",selected);
          var  selectedDate = $("#txtFromDate").datepicker("getDate");
          var msecsInADay = 5184000000;
          var endDate = new Date(selectedDate.getTime() + msecsInADay);
          $("#txtToDate").datepicker("option","maxDate",endDate);

        }
  });

  $("#txtToDate").datepicker({ 
      dateFormat: 'yy-mm-dd',
      numberOfMonths: 2,
  });
});
```

Comment: I would have guessed the same

Comment: @Daidon, the OP's question is not clear. Even he himself doesn't know what he wants to do. LOL

Comment: I think the OP might have light difficulties with english. He may formulate his question better. Otherwise I don't see how anyone is going to give a correct answer.

Comment: @Daidon, he speaks good English as what I've read. Checked his profile and he's working in Utah.

Comment: Well one can only guess. But nice idea checking the profile! He sure is not fighting with language then.

Comment: @Daidon and Ronald , sir I really appreciate for your help and time , I am sorry if I can't formulate my question , and sorry for my  bad english grammar. What I really mean is that , I am trying to create a default start and end date , the starting date will be the current date and the end date will be the plus 60 days (the last day of the plus 60 days) .

My bad if I get you wrong.

Comment: Starting date = current date or up to whatever date and end date = limits only to 60 days of the chosen start date? is that what you mean? So if I choose a start date of Dec. 10, I can only choose up to +60 days of it? But you don't want to limit your "STARTING DATE"?

Comment: Okay, look at my updated answer. You can run the code directly in SO. Is this what you want? Regards

Comment: @Teapetetose, updated my answer to reflect what you need. If you want to choose greater than +2years then just edit it to whatever range you want. :)

Comment: @Ronald regarding to your question , No that is not what I mean, what I am trying to say is that if you there will be a default date for example in the From (date today) To (02/05/2017) , that is the default date the current date today and plus 60 days, Now let's go back to my problem , If I want to change the date today into From 03/05/2017 To 03/05/2017, I can no longer do that because I have set the max date to 60 days, is there anyway on how to do it ? that I can still be able to select dates that is further or beyond to my default date range.

Comment: @Ronald Not its not ,this is what  I mean regarding to your commen " I do think he really doesn't want to limit the start date to +60 days. But the end date should be limited to up to 60 days of the chosen start date."

Comment: @Teapetetose, so my updated answer should work for you.

Comment: @Ronald the updated link does not answers my problem.

Comment: @Teapetetose, huh? I thought what I said was correct? As I said, you can adjust the +2 years to infinity as what you want.